# Toolbar's title moving down on collapsing in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I use CoordinatorLayout in fragment to get expandable toolbar (It's default example from guide)

My xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_local_see"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="\@string/lorem"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In java file I set support action bar

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity)
            .setSupportActionBar(view.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar))
```

But when i collapse toolbar, title is moved down.

[[image: Invalid title[1]]

Style of my activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Also I've tried to use default android's template from android studio (Scrolling Activity), and its works fine. However, when I replaced xml to my layout, same mistake was ocurred

How to fix it?

Comment: updated the answer please check @Nlkita

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

to your **Toolbar**

**Edit**

instead of

```
  (activity as AppCompatActivity)
        .setSupportActionBar(view.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar))
```

try this :-

```
  Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
  (( AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: where are you setting the title ? programaticaly ? @NIkitaNezhevskii

Comment: ok now remove the line `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from your toolbar and update if it works @NIkitaNezhevskii

Comment: I've setted title programmatically.
Unfortunately, removing line app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" also doesn't work. Behavior isn't changed

Comment: ok i am testing your code..in my device will inform you soon.. @NIkitaNezhevskii

Comment: in my device its working perfect.. are you using it in a fragment ? @NIkitaNezhevskii

Comment: Yes, I use it in fragment.
I don't have any additional changes because it's new application

Comment: I don't understand your corrections. How can I set toolbar to fragment without activity?

Comment: i am updating wait..slow net connection

Comment: have updated the answer please check.. @NIkitaNezhevskii

Comment: I wrote same thing on Kotlin. I rewrote your changes, nothing changed

Comment: as you have written `in java file` i thot its java.. does the problem persist? and also you can check your `styles.xml` is `NoActionBar`  included in your theme? @NIkitaNezhevskii

Comment: It was carelessness. Instead of "java-file" I meant "file with source code".
I've edited my question. I added my activity style.

Comment: anyway in my device its working perfect @NIkitaNezhevskii